# Why can't I define In-app Products before having uploaded an APK in the Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In the [documentation for testing In-App-Purchases](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) (IAPs) on Android, the following is stated:

> First, upload and publish in-app products that you want testers to be
>   able to purchase. You can upload and publish in-app products in the
>   Developer Console. **Note that you can upload and publish your in-app
>   items before you publish the APK itself**.

However, in my Google Developer Console, I can **not** define the In-app Products  before having uploaded an APK? Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct. What Google is doing here makes no sense whatsoever. But the way to get around this is to upload an empty signed APK to alpha or beta with the BILLING permission, then you can add your in-app products.

Comment: Should the signing key for dummy apk be same as that of actual app? App identifier has to be same is what I assume already

Answer (score 2):

One way around this limitation is to develop with Register https://github.com/NYTimes/Register

It is a developer library/app designed to test in app billing. In particular, once your app is using Register, you can test purchases without having to upload anything to the Play store.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to upload an apk before you can create any in-app-billing products. However you don't need to publish it to production. Just publish the apk to either alpha or beta testing, and then you will be able to create in-app-billing products without affecting your production app.

Comment: But, as for now, it takes days for google to check even closed-beta version...